# HTTP server that request a number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a http server that, receive a parameter 'number' by GET and asnwer a word 's' if number is prime or 'n' if does not. I'm using node.js and JavaScript for that, and thats what I did until now:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req,res) {

    if(req.url == 7)
        res.write('<h1>prime</h1>');

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' }); 
  res.end( );
});

server.listen(3000);

console.log('server started');
```

so, i dont understand how GET works, how can i make for receive a number by parameter? Thanks

Comment: So... what's the question? Does your code work or not work?

Comment: I edited the question, sorry about it. I want to know how  i  can make for receive a number by parameter. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just do this client-side and not waste a server trip to test it?

Comment: My exercise ask me to do a server.

Answer (score 1):

How about using some NPM modules to help you?

```
var express = require('express'); //npm install express --save
var pc = require('primecheck'); //npm install primecheck --save
var app = express();

app.get('/isprime', function (req, res) {
    // /isprime?number=3
    if (pc(req.query.number)) {
        res.send('Is Prime');
    } else {
        res.send('Not prime');
    }
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is now running.');
});
```

Comment: what's 'express' and 'primecheck' ?

Comment: ExpressJS is a web framework for nodeJS (Check link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express and http://expressjs.com) and primecheck is a simple package to check if a number is prime or not(https://www.npmjs.com/package/primecheck and https://github.com/hsarangapani/ntest)

Comment: Ok, so, where will i recieve my number value ? In page url ? How?